# Get Actual width and height of text in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am having a problem in fabric.js IText element

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText ("r",{fontSize:60, fontFamily:"arial"});

canvas.add (text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQCTd/5/).

Here you can see the 'r' element has too much extra space (padding vertically). While in properties there is no padding. I want to get the actual width and height of of this text. If I use, `activeobject.height` , it gives me the height of boundingbox.

[extraspace IText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBeSE.png)

Here is extra space showing image
[extraspace showing IText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeOuq.png)

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/tQCTd/5/

Comment: You are adding `top:-200` to text object is that necessary?

Comment: not necessary, even if we set top:0, problem is still there.

Comment: It shows blank space because that height should be calculated for all letters not for the single which is present. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/tQCTd/91/)

Comment: thanks. Is there anyway to get the actual width and height of that 'r' instead of boundingbox?

Comment: height is font size, and you can get width using [measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText)